# AWS Cloudformation: The key pair 'chaklader.pem' does not exist (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidKeyPair

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I would like to create a CloudFormation stack with the CLI command provided below:

```
$ aws cloudformation create-stack --region us-east-1 --stack-name c3-app --template-body file://starter/c3-app.yml --parameters ParameterKey=KeyPair,ParameterValue=chaklader.pem --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

My pem key is in the same folder from where I run this command:

[image]

This doesn't create the stack and I get the error message from the events log:

```
AWS Cloudformation The key pair 'chaklader.pem' does not exist (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidKeyPair.
```

My CloudFormation template is provided below:

```
Description:  This template deploys ec2 instances for the project starter

Parameters:
  AmiIdRecipeWebServiceInstance:
    Type: String
    Default: "ami-0964e67a489e13cdb"
  AmiIdAttackInstance:
    Type: String
    Default: "ami-01fcf79ce78f46764"
  KeyPair:
    Type: String
    Description: "Name of an existing KeyPair you will use to access the EC2 instances in this exercise. Be sure you have access to the private key file corresponding to this keypair."


Resources:
  InstanceRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
              - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: InstanceRolePolicy-C3
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: 's3:*'
                Resource: '*'

  InstanceProfileRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: /
      Roles:
        - !Ref InstanceRole

  WebAppSG:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: WebAppSG
      GroupDescription: "Security group for this application server"
      SecurityGroupEgress:
      - IpProtocol: -1
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: -1
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 22
        ToPort: 22
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 5000
        ToPort: 5000
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 80
        ToPort: 80
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      VpcId: !ImportValue VpcId

  RecipeWebServiceInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: !Ref AmiIdRecipeWebServiceInstance
      InstanceType: t3.micro
      KeyName: !Ref KeyPair
      SecurityGroupIds:
      - !GetAtt WebAppSG.GroupId
      SubnetId: !ImportValue PublicSubnetTrusted
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref InstanceProfileRole
      Tags:
      - Key: "Name"
        Value: "Web Service Instance - C3"
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          Fn::Sub:
            - |
              #!/bin/bash
              echo "Environment=S3_FREE_RECIPES="${S3FreeRecipies} | sudo tee -a /lib/systemd/system/flask.service
              echo "Environment=S3_SECRET_RECIPES="${S3SecretRecipies} | sudo tee -a /lib/systemd/system/flask.service
              systemctl daemon-reload
              sleep 30
              service flask restart
            - S3FreeRecipies: !ImportValue BucketNameRecipesFree
              S3SecretRecipies: !ImportValue BucketNameRecipesSecret

# Add code for Exercise 3

  AppLoadBalancerSG:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: AppLoadBalancerSG
      GroupDescription: "Security group for this application server"
      SecurityGroupEgress:
      - IpProtocol: -1
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 80
        ToPort: 80
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      VpcId: !ImportValue VpcId

  AppEIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Properties:
      InstanceId: !Ref RecipeWebServiceInstance

  AppLoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Name: c1-web-service-alb
      SecurityGroups:
      - !GetAtt AppLoadBalancerSG.GroupId
      Subnets:
        - !ImportValue PublicSubnetTrusted
        - !ImportValue PublicSubnetUnTrusted

  AppLoadBalancerListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: forward
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref AppTargetGroup
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref AppLoadBalancer
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP

  AppTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      HealthCheckEnabled: true
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 10
      HealthCheckPath: /health
      Name: AppTargetGroup
      Port: 5000
      VpcId: !ImportValue VpcId
      Protocol: HTTP
      Targets:
      - Id: !Ref RecipeWebServiceInstance

  AttackInstanceSG:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: AttackInstanceSG
      GroupDescription: "Security group for the attack instance"
      SecurityGroupEgress:
      - IpProtocol: -1
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 22
        ToPort: 22
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      VpcId: !ImportValue VpcId

  AttackInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: !Ref AmiIdAttackInstance
      InstanceType: t3.micro
      KeyName: !Ref KeyPair
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref InstanceProfileRole
      SecurityGroupIds:
      - !GetAtt AttackInstanceSG.GroupId
      SubnetId: !ImportValue PublicSubnetUnTrusted
      Tags:
      - Key: "Name"
        Value: "Attack Instance - C3"

Outputs:
  AttackInstanceIP:
    Value: !GetAtt AttackInstance.PublicDnsName
  ApplicationInstanceIP:
    Value: !GetAtt RecipeWebServiceInstance.PublicDnsName
  ApplicationURL:
    Value: !GetAtt AppLoadBalancer.DNSName
```

I created a new keypair with the command provided as suggested in answer:

```
aws ec2 create-key-pair --key-name arefe --query "KeyMaterial" --output text > arefe.pem

chmod 400 arefe.pem
```

[image]

Then, run the command again:

```
 aws cloudformation create-stack --region us-east-1 --stack-name c3-app --template-body file://starter/c3-app.yml --parameters ParameterKey=KeyPair,ParameterValue=arefe.pem --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

I still receive the same error:

```
The key pair 'arefe.pem' does not exist (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidKeyPair.NotFound; Request ID: aceed5ea-7841-4056-8738-e02a1f921b90; Proxy: null)
```

What's the issue here?

Comment: What is your template?

Comment: @Marcin The CloudFormation file is provided for stack creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFormation (CFN) is not going to take your `chaklader.pem` and create a pair key in AWS. You have to do it before hand yourself. And you can't use CFN for that as it is not supported, unless you will program such a logic yourself using [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html).

The easiest way is  to [create or import](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#prepare-key-pair) the key "manually" using AWS Console, SDK or CLI. Then you can reference its name in your template.

Comment: I tried using the command that you mentioned and created a new key pair from the terminal. When I tried the command I still get the same error. Whats the issue now?

Comment: @Arefe Your key name is `arefe`, not `arefe.pem`. You use the wrong name in `ParameterKey=KeyPair,ParameterValue=arefe.pem`.